# Receiving multiple images over TCP socket using InputStream

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, inputstream

I am trying to send multiple images one by one automatically from my android phone to the Server (PC) each time I capture an image from the camera.

The problem is the `read()` function only blocks the first time. So, technically only one image is received and shown perfectly. But after that when `is.read()` returns `-1`, this function does not block and multiple images could not receive.

The code is simple for the Server

```
while (true) {
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    is = sock.getInputStream();

    if (is != null)
        System.out.println("is not null");

    int bufferSize = sock.getReceiveBufferSize();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
    while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
    {
        if (filewritecheck == true)
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\fypimages\\image" + imgNum + ".jpeg");
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            imgNum++;
            filewritecheck = false;
        }
        bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
        System.out.println("count: " + count);
    }
    if (count <= 0 && bos != null) {
        filewritecheck = true;
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

The output after the image is received is

```
is not null
is not null
is not null
is not null
is not null
is not null
is not null
is not null
...
...
...
...
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive multiple images over the same stream you should establish some kind of protocol, example: read an int that represent the number of bytes of each image.

```
<int><b1><b2><b3>...<bn> <int><b1><b2><b3>...<bn> ...
```

Then you can read each image this way:

```
...
is = sock.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

if (is != null)
    System.out.println("is not null");

while (true) {
    // Read first 4 bytes, int representing the lenght of the following image
    int imageLength = (bis.read() << 24) + (bis.read() << 16) + (bis.read() << 8) + bis.read();

    // Create the file output
    fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\fypimages\\image" + imgNum + ".jpeg");
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    imgNum++;

    // Read the image itself
    int count = 0;
    while (count < imageLength) {
        bos.write(bis.read());
        count += 1;
    }
    bos.close();
}
```

Note that you also have to modify the sender, and put the imageLength in the same byte order than you are receving it.

Also note that reading and writting one byte at a time isn't the most efficient way, but it's easier and the buffered streams take care of most of the performance impact.