# InputStream to receive files twice explicitly

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I am trying to send two images with a difference of 5 seconds between them from an android phone (client) to PC(server).
I am using InputStream to do this for me.

```
        ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(27508);
        Socket sock = servsock.accept();
        System.out.println("connection accepted ");
        int count;

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        is = sock.getInputStream();

        int bufferSize = sock.getReceiveBufferSize();


        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        System.out.println("Here1");
        fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\fypimages\\image" + imgNum + ".jpeg");
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        imgNum++;
        while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
        {
            bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
            System.out.println("count: " + count);
        }
        bos.flush();


        bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
        System.out.println("Here2");
        fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\fypimages\\image" + imgNum + ".jpeg");
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        imgNum++;
        while ((count = is.read(bytes)) > 0)
        {
            bos.write(bytes, 0, count);
            System.out.println("count: " + count);
        }
        bos.flush();


        System.out.println("Here3");
```

The problem is `is.read(bytes)` blocks the code only for the first image and then the program is terminated and it does not block for the second image.

I know it returns `-1` when the first image is recieved completely, but how do I make it work for the second time ?

Comment: This is just a repost of your own earlier question  [Recieving multiple images over TCP socket using InputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189128/recieving-multiple-images-over-tcp-socket-using-inputstream)

Answer (score 1):

If `read` returns -1, it means other side closed the connection. But your  basic problem seems to be, you're not handling the connection as stream. In a data stream, there are no inherent "packages", in this case no built-in way to distinguish one image from next.

You can proceed in at least 3 different ways:

- Add your own simple protocol, for example: at sending side, write number of bytes in image, then write image bytes, then write number of bytes in next image, then write next image, etc, without closing the connection. And at receiving side, loop first reading the number of bytes, then reading that many bytes of image data.
- Write one image per connection, then close the connection and create new connection for next image.
- In this case, because data is JPEG images, just write all JPEG images as one data stream, then on receiving side, parse the JPEG format to see where the image boundaries are.

First choice is most efficient, and also is easily extended to deliver image name or other extra data in addition to image file length. Second is ok, and most simple and robust (for example, no need to worry about byte order, or worry about getting out of sync between sender and receiver), if there aren't too many images, but if there are hundreds of images, then re-connecting is going to slow things down a bit. Third choice is probably not the way to go with JPEGs, just listed is as a possiblity.

Comment: What about if I do not have any fixed number of images to send ? Can I make it happen without closing the connection and reconnecting again and again ?

Comment: And also I mentioned there is a difference of 5 seconds between sending of two images, so first one probably wont work ?

Comment: Having fixed number of images shouldn't matter. Doing it the first way, after reading the last image, and trying to receive length of next, `read` would return `-1` because sender would presumably have closed the connection. Delay of 5 seconds shouldn't matter for any method, as read will block if needed, but with that image speed, having a new connection for each image should not be a problem either (it will increase latency by some milliseconds, but that's probably irrelevant in your use case).